# Multiplication error in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't get my head around a multiplication problem I'm having in Python 2.7. I'm sure the answer is very simple! As you can tell from the simplicity of my code I am a beginner (see below).

```
from __future__ import division

goAgain = 'yes'

while goAgain == 'yes':
    meal = raw_input('How much did your meal cost? ')
    tip = raw_input('Do you want to tip a set PRICE or a PERCENTAGE of your total bill? ').upper()
    print

    if tip == 'PRICE':
        tip = raw_input('How much do you want to tip? ')
        bill = int(meal) + int(tip)
        print 'As your meal cost ' + str(meal) + ' and your tip is ' + str(tip) + ', your total bill is ' + str(bill) + '.'
    elif tip == 'PERCENTAGE':
        tip = raw_input('What percentage would you like to tip? ')
        tip = int(tip) / 100
        print 'Your tip is ' + str(tip)
        bill = (int(meal) * int(tip)) + int(meal) # This is where my problem is
        print 'The bill is ' + str(bill)
        print 'As your meal cost ' + str(meal) + ' and you tipped ' + str(tip) + ' percent, your total bill is ' + str(bill) + '.'
    else:
        tip = raw_input("Sorry, I didn't catch that! Do you want to tip a set PRICE or a PERCENTAGE of your total bill? ").upper()
```

The issue I'm having is that the program always tells me that my total bill is the same price as the meal variable, despite (what I can see) that I'm adding the meal and the tip values together.

Comment: You should be using `float` instead of `int` for your numbers, because `int` is for integers and `float` is for numbers with decimals, and your `tip` value should be a decimal after dividing by 100.

Answer (score 1):

You divide `tip` by hundred, getting a number less than 1 (which is quite reasonable). Then when you are multiplying it, you cast it to an integer. `(int(meal) * int(tip)) + int(meal)`

If you cast a number between 0 and 1 to an `int`, you get zero.

Instead, if you want to cast the result to an integer, you could do this:

```
bill = int(int(meal)*tip) + int(meal)
```

or you might want to try casting to `float` throughout instead of `int`. It might give more appropriate results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (as @khelwood already pointed out) is that dividing two integers with `/` in Python 2 always gives an integer, so your effective tip rate is zero.

The root of the problem is that you're using Python 2. Division in Python 2 is unintuitive, but continues to work this way for reasons of backward compatibility. You can resolve it once and for all by switching to Python 3, or by adding the following at the top of your script(s):

```
from __future__ import division
```

You'll then always get a float when you use `/` to divide two numbers. (There's also `//`, which will also give you an integer result.)

Comment: That's not really the problem in this case. After the `tip` variable is divided by 100, the code in the question **explicitly casts** it to an `int`. That gives zero in any version of Python.

Comment: You're right... they're both problems and both need to be fixed, though.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have used:

```
tip = int(tip) / 100
```

`tip` is now a float:

```
>>> tip = int(tip) / 100
>>> type(tip)
<type 'float'>
```

So when you do:

```
(int(meal) * int(tip)) + int(meal)
```

you convert your float (that is <1) to an int, so it will become 0:

```
>>> int(0.7)
0
```

So `(int(meal) * int(tip)) + int(meal)` is `(int(meal) * 0) + int(meal) = int(meal)`.
In order to achieve what you want, you don't have to cast tip:

```
bill = (int(meal) * tip) + int(meal)
```

However, you could cast the result if you want:

```
bill = int((int(meal) * tip) + int(meal))
```